# Как объяснить расстановку запятых в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, сложное-предложение

*Не знаю, в какой другой литературе показали стихотворцы такое бесконечное разнообразие оттенков звука, чему отчасти, разумеется, способствовал сам поэтический язык наш* (Н. В. Гоголь).

Comment: Исправила, может сейчас получится?

Comment: А точка есть у Гоголя? А пробелы?

Comment: Теперь всë нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю,(1) в какой другой литературе показали стихотворцы такое бесконечное разнообразие оттенков звука,(2) чему отчасти,(3) разумеется,(4) способствовал сам поэтический язык наш.

В предложении три основы: *не знаю, стихотворцы показали, язык способствовал*.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение с последовательным (цепным) подчинением. В таких предложениях придаточные отделяются от главного предложения и друг от друга запятой (1, 2).
[Разумеется](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_649) — это вводное слово, обрамляется запятыми (3, 4).
[Отчасти](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) — это наречие; запятые не нужны.

[Сложное предложение с последовательным подчинением](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-slozhnopodchinennyih-predlozheniy-posledovatelnyim-podchineniem.html)